# Extract Date in Python Dictionary Key, where Key is of type np.datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, dictionary

I have a python dictionary where the keys are all of type`np.datetime64`. I only want to keep the `"yyyy-mm-dd"`-part.
The dictionary-keys look like this:

`dict_keys([numpy.datetime64('2018-01-01T00:00:00.000000000') ...`

When I use:

```
import pandas as pd
for key in df.keys():
    key = pd.to_datetime(key)
    key = key.date()
    print(key)
```

I get this as output (what actually is what I want the keys to be):

```
2018-01-01
2018-01-03
2018-01-06
2018-01-08
2018-01-11
```

But this obviously doesn't change the keys in my original dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `del` and then create the new `key` within your loop. This should work I believe:

```
for key,value in df.items():
    del df[key] #Delete the datetime object, used as key
    key = pd.to_datetime(key) #Trasnform into a datetime object
    key = key.date() #Retain only the date part 
    df[key] = value #Create a key with only the date, keeping the original value for the key
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the datetime objects to strings:

```py
keys = [str(date) for date in my_dict.keys()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works:
Extracting the keys, converting them into string, splitting on 'T', zipping new keys with the old dictionary values and then finally creating the new dict.

```
new_dict = dict(zip([str(x).split('T')[0] for x in my_dict.keys()], my_dict.values()))
```